# Check InternetExplorer Object in client side . 

Tags: javascript, vbscript

Is there a code in javascript  or VBscript to check by the client side  whether  a webpage is loaded in normal internet explorer IE , or InternetExplorer Object (inside a software ) ?

Thanks .

Comment: Have you looked at the useragent? They might differ somehow. If not you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Both have the same useragent .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is to block attacks ?

You can check document.referrer but keep in mind that under certain circumstances this too can be spoofed, see this http://www.cgisecurity.com/lib/XmlHTTPRequest.shtml article to learn more about that.

Comment: Hi , it is not attack issue . There must be something in iexploreobject that we can check

Comment: have you checked document.referrer ? il would help if you publish a runnable piece of code

Comment: There is no referrer here , the request is direct . Both IE and Ie object have the same UserAgent . by IE object i mean the internet explorer that embed into a software .

Comment: in your code, do you have access to the DOM ? if so you can get to the referrer, i realy advise you to publish what you've got of code, it's difficult to help you like this. the useragent was a suggestion from Thiefmaster which i think won't work out since indeed they will be the same either way